# Excel table relationship manager

Tags: excel

I have two tables in Excel that I'm trying to create a relationship between and I can't seem to understand why it is not working.

**Table1:** Consists of a Region and Health Board field. (Health Board values consists of text, hidden as they're for my project)

[image: e]

**Table 2**: Consists of unique region codes and again text which i've hidden. 
[image]

I've tried to create a relationship between the two fields: (1 to many relationship) but I'm getting a warning saying that both entries should be unique. Why is this the case?

[image]

Now when i go to make a pivot table to display a summary based on the two... it cannot find the relationship.

In the pivot options, I am attempting to put region column from table 2 as the rows and health board (text) values as the values. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you *sure* there are no duplicates in your Region code column?

Comment: Yeah checked that. I think it might of been the way I was trying to arrange my rows/columns when making the pivot table. Is there a certain way you must structure based on whatever column is the unique value? I can't see that being the case but...

Comment: I was really addressing the error you mentioned when creating the relationship.

Comment: oh right, sorry.